# Big O of this equation?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, nested-loops

```
 for (int j=0,k=0; j<n; j++)
   for (double m=1; m<n; m*=2)
      k++;
```

I think it's O(n^2) but I'm not certain. I'm working on a practice problem and I have the following choices:

- O(n^2)
- O(2^n)
- O(n!)
- O(n log(n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its **O(nlog<sub>2</sub>n)**. The code block runs n*log<sub>2</sub>n times.

Suppose `n=16`; Then the first loop runs 16 (=n) times. And the second loops runs 4(=log<sub>2</sub>n) times (m=1,2,4,8). So the inner statement `k++` runs 64 times = (n*log<sub>2</sub>n) times.

Comment: Besides being wrong, the question is tagged homework, so you should provide hints and explanations, not simply the result.

Comment: @JanHudec I did't know conventions about *homework* tag. Explanation added. Thanks.

Comment: You should also be careful not to provide the wrong answer, as you did prior to your edit.

Comment: @d3v3us, Yeah. In fact I missed the `*` which I shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks. It makes perfect sense..... Also because of how exponents relate to logarithms, stated previously by d3v3us. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im your approche is correct. However, we're not suppose to give assumptions.In School, We are always asked to find our r which is the incrementer and by finding it will leads us to the result O(n lgn) . But not to assume to find the number of execution.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm... well, break it down.

It seems obvious that the outer loop is O(n).  It is increasing by 1 each iteration.
The inner loop however, increases by a power of 2.  Exponentials are certainly related (in fact inversely) to logarithms.

Why have you come to the O(n^2) solution?  Prove it.

Comment: Well I have no proof. I know it's not n! though it can be true for small n's. n^2 seemed logical since big-O complexity is never interpreted completely accurately and since there are nested for loops with an outer loop of n iterations and an inner loop of less iterations. I guess my initial answer was just a guess, truthfully.

Comment: Ok.  Now we are getting somewhere.  Providing your above comment in your initial question would have provided more insight into what you were thinking.  Eliminating n! for example.

Comment: I was just going through the practice problems thinking this was much harder than it actually was. Because of you and Shiplu I worked it out on my own with various test values (1, 5, 8, 16, 32, 64). There is no real reason for the number to be inaccurate since the log(n) is undoing what's effectively 2^m. Thanks, I should try harder next time.

Comment: Nah, you did fine.  I think your bigger error was in assigning the checkmark to an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

lets look at the worst-case behaviour.  for second loop search continues from  1, 2, 4, 8.... lets say n is 2^k for some k >= 0. in the worst-case we might end up searching until 2^k and realise we overshot the target. Now we know that target can be in 2^(k - 1) and 2^k. The number of elements in that range are 2^(k - 1) (think a second.). The number of elements that we have examined so far is O(k) which is O(logn) and for first loop it's O(n).(too simple to find out). then order of whole code will O(n(logn)).

Answer (score 1):

A generic way to approach these sorts of problems is to consider the order of each loop, and because they are nested, you can multiply the "O" notations.

Some simple rules for big "O":

1. `O(n)O(m) = O(nm)`
2. `O(n) + O(m) = O(n + m)`
3. `O(kn) = O(n)` where 'k' is some constant

The 'j' loop iterates across n elements, so clearly it is O(n).
The 'm' loop iterates across log(n) elements, so it is O(log(n)).

Since the loops are nested, our final result would `O(n) * O(log(n)) = O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: To clarify, the inner loop's variable `m` multiplies itself by 2, so it reaches `n` by moving like: 1, 2, 4, 8, ..., `2^(log(n) + 1)`

Comment: Sorry about that, I just joined tonight and hadn't realized about the homework convention!